# java Normalizer behave different on different machines

Tags: java, string, multilingual

this piece of code works fine on development envoirement but not on production.

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
public class TestNorm {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
                String s = "";

                for (String s1: args) {
                        s = s + " " + s1;
                }

                System.out.println(Normalizer.normalize(s.toLowerCase(), Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "").replaceAll("[^\\p{Alnum}]+", "-").replaceAll("^[^a-z0-9]+", "").replaceAll("[^a-z0-9]+$", ""));
        }
}
```

(blank)

```
DevEnv$ java TestNorm hellö 
> hello
```

(blank)

```
ProdEnv$ java TestNorm hellö
> hell
```

**What am I missing? Why didnt I get the same Normalizer result; "hello"?**

could be an useful info to know

```
DevEnv$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
```

(blank)

```
ProdEnv$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_01"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_01-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 21.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: @DanielFischer most probably. still don't know how to or what to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found a solution for all who have the same problem!

I looked into this website;
http://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment

executed this;

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

and tested with this

```
perl -Mcharnames=:full -CS -wle 'print "\N{EURO SIGN}"'
```

output should be "€"

the code that I wrote above will work too...